# Sarissa using an existing XML Doc Object?

Tags: jquery, xml

I am writing an app that depends heavily on XML data sources.  For purposes outside of this scope, the XML is loaded with jQuery.ajax().  Is there a way to insert the resulting XML Doc Object into a Sarissa Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this:

var oDomDoc = Sarissa.getDomDocument();
oDomDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xDoc, "text/xml");